react-query: Detect first first fetch
I have two views when fetching:

Initial one, when you see a component for the first time.
When you changed filters inside this component, so header inside should be displayed and content at the bottom should show spinner.

I'm using status === 'pending' for detecting whether data is fetching.
Is there a way to check if I'm fetching data for the first time?
i.e. when I'm fetching for 2nd time it's definitely coming from filters and I need to display a different view.

No need to use useRef. An easy way to achieve this is using keepPreviousData

import { useQuery, keepPreviousData } from '@tanstack/react-query';

//...

const { data, isPlaceholderData, status, error } = useQuery({
  queryKey: [‘component’, params, onSuccess],
  queryFn: () => fetchData(params, onSuccess),
  enabled,
  placeholderData: keepPreviousData,
  staleTime: 0
});

//...

return (<div>
  <header>This element will be visible when you fetch data again</header>
    {isPlaceholderData
       ? <Loading>
       : <div>Your data ({data}) will be displayed here</div>
    }
 </div>);


When using placeholderData and keepPreviousData, then the data remains populated when a new fetch is happening due to the query key changing. And isPlaceholderData  can be used to to show the loading UI during that time.
Live demo of separate loading UIs

This looks pretty cool, thanks for sharing!
In this case, how would you handle errors? The one when data fetching failed and filters were not shown, and the other one when you've clicked on filter but error got thrown.

You could simply check the params when you display the error, and if its populated then display a filters error

Thanks for a reply, accepted this answer as the right one. However, in my case I use isFetching instead of isPlaceholderData. When I'm fetching data, no matter if it's placeholder data or not, I still need to display a spinner, so isFetching is better for this case.

Solved it by using useRef() hook. Basically you count how many times data has been fetched. If count === 0 - data is fetching for the first time. Sharing an example below:
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const Loading = () => <>Loading...</>;

// Function for retrieving data
const fetchData = async (params, onSuccess) => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
    const response = await fetch(`${ENDPOINT_URL}?${searchParams.toString()}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(data?.message || 'Oops something went wrong');
    }

    if (onSuccess) {
        onSuccess(data);
    }

    return data;
};

const Component = ({ params }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const fetchCountRef = useRef(0);
    const onSuccess = (data) => {
        /**
         * Fetched one more time
         */
        fetchCountRef.current += 1;
        setData(data);
    };

    const { data, status, error } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['component', params, onSuccess],
        queryFn: () => fetchData(params, onSuccess),
        enabled,
        staleTime: 0
    });
    const fetching = status === 'pending';
    /**
     * Check if you're fetching for the first time
     */ 
    const isInitialFetch = fetchCountRef += 1;

    if (error) {
        return <div>{error?.message}</div>;
    }

    /**
     * Gets displayed when fetching for the first time
     */ 
    if (isInitialFetch && fetching) {
        return <Loading />;
    }

    return <div>
        <header>This element will be visible when you fetch data again</header>
        {fetching
            ? <Loading>
            : <div>Your data ({data}) will be displayed here</div>
        }
    </div>;
};

Haven't tested code but I hope you get the idea. It's pretty easy & neat.
